# How to create JUnit 5 based unit test for project that implements Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security

How can I create unit tests for a project that implements Springs `AuthenticationProver` and extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`? For now, I've added MockBeans for my `authenticationService``` and the test runs, but I don't think this is the correct approach.

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
@WebMvcTest(PortfolioController.class)
public class PortfolioControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private JacksonTester<Portfolio> json;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    private PortfolioService portfolioService;

    @MockBean
    private AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    // Removing test methods for brevity
}
```

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationService implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final HashService hashService;

    public AuthenticationService(UserRepository userRepository, HashService hashService) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.hashService = hashService;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // Removing implementation details for brevity
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationService authenticationService) {
        this.authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.authenticationService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Removing implementation details for brevity
    }
}
```

Comment: On a more unit-test like level and to test one of your controller in isolation you can use `@WebMvcTest` (like you already do) and mock only the beans that your `AuthenticationService` depends on. Next, specify their behavior (e.g. the what the `UserRepository` should return) and then invoke your endpoint with `MockMvc`.  `MockMvc` also comes with a [great integration for Spring Security](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/). 

For an integration test, go with `@SpringBootTest` and access your app over HTTP.

Comment: So adding the @MockBean on ```AuthenticationService``` is sufficient? I read through the link you provided and am a bit confused. They give an example with ```shouldReturnLocationOfReviewWhenUserIsAuthenticatedAndCreatesReview``` and attach a user named "Duke". I assume there's some setup code that isn't being shown?

Comment: The setup in the linked example happens for your in the background. Spring Boot instruments the MockMvc instance to use your security config. I wouldn't add `@MockBean` on the auth service but rather the dependent beans of the auth service

Comment: @rieckpil If Spring instruments the MockMvc instance why is it not authenticating me? Do I need to add mvcMatchers?:

`@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/dashboard").permitAll()
        .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/tasks/**").authenticated()
        .mvcMatchers("/**").authenticated()
      )
      .httpBasic();
  }
}

Comment: @rieckpil also reading through the link shown below and it seems I shouldn't be using `@MockBean` for unit testing at all. That seems to be reserved for integration testing.

https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/

Comment: Spring instruments the `MockMvc` instance to apply your security config. You still have to use e.g. `@WithMockUser` to "authenticate" and place a user in the `SecurityContext`.

Regarding `@MockBean`. This depends on where you draw the line between unit and integration tests. I personally see `@WebMvcTest` as unit-like tests for the controller level and hence use `@MockBean` to mock out any underlying layer.